# Ask question about VM management in Azure

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

Where do I ask questions about VM management on Microsoft Azure?

I know this question is off topic on Stack Overflow and on Unix & Linux there is no azure tag. However it's not an Ubuntu question to ask on askubuntu.com.

Where I must ask it or similar question like this?

**Title** : Move an existing VM into a proximity placement group in Azure

**Question**: CLI equivalent to the following:

```
$ppg = Get-AzProximityPlacementGroup -ResourceGroupName myPPGResourceGroup -Name myPPG
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name myVM
Stop-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName
Update-AzVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -ProximityPlacementGroupId $ppg.Id
Start-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName
```

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/azure

Comment: Albeit that they are likely to point out that PowerShell *is* a CLI tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your question on Microsoft Q&A platform.

> Q. What is Microsoft Q&A

A. Microsoft Q&A is a global, community-driven platform for timely, high-quality technical answers. Q&A is replacing MSDN and TechNet forums.

You can ask a question on Microsoft Q&A:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html

Remember to add the tag for Azure VM is `azure-virtual-machines`

[image]

**Reference:** [Microsoft Q&A - Frequently Asked Questions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/articles/388/microsoft-qa-frequently-asked-questions.html)

Comment: Thank you! However I mean to ask in stackExchange community. But I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @majidhajibaba not all questions have a home on SE.